# REST collections, good practice to do: GET api/CollectionA/<collection id>/CollectionB?

Tags: rest, collections

I need to be able to grab a collection based on a collection of objects. For this, I'm considering a couple of approaches, but am not sure which one makes the most sense, so I'll post them both. If there is a better way that I may not have considered, then please feel free to post your suggestion(s) :)

For example, I'll use Products and Reviews (which are reviews of products) as resources.

Objective:
We want to get the Reviews for all of the Products

Approach A:

```
POST api/Products { json: filters, limits, etc } // returns api/Products/<id>
GET api/Products/<id>/Reviews { json: filters, limits, etc } // returns json array 
// ... of reviews present in products
// id in this case would refer to the collection, which would be cached
```

Approach B:

```
GET api/Reviews { json: filters } // returns json array of reviews, but needs to 
// ... have either all of the product ids passed as an array (not practical with 
// ... huge collections), or needs to have all of the api/Products filters passed, 
// ... in which case making the code unDRY
```

Approach C:

```
GET api/Reviews { json: filters: { products: 'api/Products?filters' }...
// is this reasonable?
```

Thanks in advance for any help, and apologies if this question is noob, I'm still new to REST

Approach D:

```
access individual products
GET api/Product/<id>

access collection of products:
POST api/Products?filters=stuff..
GET api/Products/<id>

access collection of products' reviews

POST api/Products/<id>/Reviews?filters=stuff
GET api/Products/<id>/Reviews/<id>

... this would thus allow us to cache the result easily, does this seem reasonable to you?
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Objective: We want to get the Reviews for all of the Products

Basically, `GET /api/products/<id>` should return a `product`, and `GET /api/products/<id>/reviews` should return all `reviews` for a given `product`.

If you want to fetch all `products`, you will use `GET /api/products`. As you consider both `reviews` and `products` as resources, I recommend you to expose all `reviews`:

```
GET /api/reviews
```

But you probably want `products` **with** their `reviews`. That would mean fetching some products using `/api/products` (and a set of filters for example) and **expanding** the result set with `reviews`. This `expand` term comes from the OData protocol: http://www.odata.org/documentation/uri-conventions#ExpandSystemQueryOption.

You could do:

```
GET /api/products?$expand=reviews

GET /api/products?filter=foo&$expand=reviews
```

This URI means: "identifies the collection of `products` as well as each of the `reviews` associated with each `product`.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer the question William, however, in this case, I'm just looking to get all of the reviews associated with a collection of products, not the products themselves. In addition, these Reviews are or products specifically. The conundrum is thus that I don't want to have unDRY code, and also don't want to return too much data (as it could be a very big result set of products that we're working with). Is there anything similar to $expand that would ignore the parents?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think so. Another solution would be to get all your `products`, and then to fetch `reviews` product by product, it's REST but it's not really pragmatic. So, filtering `/reviews` on product ids seems the best approach: `/reviews?productIds=1,2,3`

Comment: Off chance do you know of any message board where I might discuss REST design patterns with people? I am at a point where I have a lot of ideas about how I *think* rest should be implemented, but I'm just not sure. For example, in my opinion, I think that api/Products/<id> should refer to a collection, since it's a resource, and as such, to create the resource, you should first POST with an expiry header, which would thus allow for caching. In my opinion it makes sense for individual products to be accessed with api/Product/<id>, and collections with api/Products/<id>

Comment: .. because I have already considered your suggested solution, and it's impractical with massive datasets, and as mentioned just now, doing things that way would allow for easy caching AND allow me to do stuff like POST api/Products/<id>/Reviews?filters=stuff.. and then api/Products/<id>/Reviews/<id> to take advantage of caching avoid making too many database queries server side.. I'm updating the original message to make this more clear, please let me know what you think :)