# REST url proper format

Tags: rest

my REST API format:

```
http://example.com/api/v1.0/products - get all products
http://example.com/api/v1.0/products/3 - get product with id=3
```

Also, the products can be orginized into a product groups.

What is a proper way to get all product groups according to REST best practices:

```
http://example.com/api/v1.0/products/groups
```

or

```
http://example.com/api/v1.0/productgroups
```

...

another option ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't agree with Rishabh Soni because `http://example.com/api/v1.0/products/groups` may lead to ambiguity.

I would put my money on `http://example.com/api/v1.0/productgroups` or even better `http://example.com/api/v1.0/product_groups` (better readability).

I've had similar discussion here: [Updating RESTful resources against aggregate roots only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41739067/updating-restful-resources-against-aggregate-roots-only/)

> Question: About the thing of /products/features or /product-features,
>   is there any consensus on this? Do you know any good source to ensure
>   that it's not just a matter of taste?
>
> Answer: I think this is misleading. **I would expect to get all features
>   in all products rather than get all possible features.** But, to be
>   honest, it’s hard to find any source talking directly about this
>   problem, but there is a bunch of articles where people don’t try to
>   create nested resources like /products/features, but do this
>   [separately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12150218/rest-collections-good-practice-to-do-get-api-collectiona-collection-id-colle).

So, we can't be sure `http://example.com/api/v1.0/products/groups` will return all possible groups or just all groups that are connected with all existing products (what about a group that has not been connected with the product yet?).

To avoid this ambiguity, you can add some annotation in documentation. But you can just prepare `http://example.com/api/v1.0/product_groups` and all is clear.

Comment: There is no general rule but Look at these two  microsoft azure rest api url, same until op.-
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/$subs/resourceGroups/$resGrp/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/rishabhvm/start?api-version=2015-05-01
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/$subs/resourceGroups/$res_grp/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/rishabhvm?api-version=2015-05-01
And for another instance think if later he wants to fetch info about some another item in the "product" entity. By this he had to build different keyword for different items in the same category.

Comment: @RishabhSoni It's not the same case. Example from Azure shows pattern `/resources/$id/sub_resource/$subresource_id/...` The question is about `/resources/subresources`. To get info about one subresource: `/products/$id/product_group`. Another: `/products/$id/price` and so on.  `Product_groups` is a dictionary.  Could you explain complications? I am not sure we are talking about the same point.

Comment: @RishabhSoni `Product_groups` is a dictionary. `/products/$id/product_group` might have a link to `product_groups/$id`. Relations between resource, that's an essence of rest.

Answer (score 1):

If you are developing Rest API for your clients than you should not rely on id's. Instead build a meaningful abbreviation and map them to actual id on server side.

If that is not possible, instead of using 
`http://example.com/api/v1.0/products/3` you can use `http://example.com/api/v1.0/products?product_id=3` and then you can provide "product_id" description in the documentation. basically telling the client ways to use product_id.
In short a url must be meaningful and follow a pattern.The variable part must be send by in the url query(part after ? or POST payload)

With this, method to querying the server is also important. If client is trying to get something to the server he should use "GET" http request, similar POST http request if it is uploading new info and "PUT" request if it is updating or creating a new resource.

So by this analogy `http://example.com/api/v1.0/products/groups` is more appropriate as it is following a pattern(groups in product) while productgroups is more like a keyword with no pattern.

A directory like pattern is more easier to understand. Like in file systems(C:\Program Files\WinRAR), every part gets us to more generalized target.

You can also customize this for specific group- http://example.com/api/v1.0/products/groups?id=3

Comment: Thanks for your answer but my question was mostly about `/products/groups` vs `/productgroups` patterns and rules how to determine this.